# How do I access an element of 'Other" namespace in XS

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Sample Schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="ClassTest">
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:element name="Class" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"maxOccurs="Unbound" />
```

Sample XML:

```
<ClassTestxmlns="http://schooltest.com">
 <Name>AAA</Name>
 <Class>3</Class>
 <ns:maths>33</ns:maths>
 <ps:english>44<ps:english>
</ClassTest>
```

How do I refer the elements maths and english which have different namespace to target namespace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is tagged as XSLT 2.0, you could also consider to use a wildcard e.g. `*:maths` and `*:english`, that selects elements with local name `maths` respectively `english` in any namespace.

Comment: Martin, I understand the question as: How do we select *any* element matched by "any" in the schema. This means that we generally don't know what names such elements could have. In that sense, this answer isn't actually the answer wanted by the OP, because it uses hardcoded names that may or maynot be present in the XML document.

Comment: I went by the XML sample given and the question asked related to that sample. It might be that your reading of the complete question is correct, let's simply wait until Viswanath comments. As for your answer, with the question being tagged as `xslt-2.0` I think you should also mention the XSLT/XPath 2.0 `except` e.g. `/x:ClassTest/(* except (x:Name, x:Class))`.

Comment: Martin, While one could provide XPath 2.0 expressions that aren't XPath 1.0 expressions (and this is easier), it is of greater value to provide expressions that are both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 as this increases the applicability of the solution. Our purpose is not to boast with our XSLT 2.0 knowledge (which people undoubtedly know both of us possess), but to provide a solution that has maximim value to the widest possible user audience. In other words, the value of an XPath 2.0 expression is when it fills the gap of what cannot (or is more difficult to) be expressed as an XPath 1.0 expression

Comment: I think `/x:ClassTest/(* except (x:Name, x:Class))` is worth mentioning, of course not to boast with XSLT 2.0 knowledge, but rather as that approach is less limited as the `self` axis test that XPath/XSLT 1.0 provides. For instance you an easily apply the XSLT/XPath 2.0 approach for attributes as well e.g. `//*/(@* except (@foo, @bar))` while XPath 1.0 kind of lacks that expressive power.

Comment: Are you saying that there isn't an equivalent XPath expression? This, of course, isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I refer the elements maths and english which have different
>   namespace to target namespace.

**Because nothing is known in advance about the namespace and name of such an element, it is only safe to select them without using any particular name or namespace**:

```
/x:ClassTest/*[not(self::x:Name or self::x:Class)]
```

Where the prefix `"x:"` must be bound to the namespace `"http://schooltest.com"` .

This expression selects any element that is a child of the top element `x:ClassTest` and is not one of the elements `x:Name` or `x:Class`. When applied on the provided XML document, it selects both the `ns:maths` and the `ps:english` elements.